# Cannot open most of pre-installed apps (include App Store) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-store, windows-store-app

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1

However, I cannot open App Store and most of pre-installed apps. You can see in the photo below, they're grey.

[image: Error]

If I click on it, for example, Photos, it will say:
[image: Error]

And when I click "Go to the Store", or open the App Store, it opens up and closes immediately.

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

**Edit!**

This is what I got when running `wsreset`:
[image: Wsreset]

Answer (score 2):

Windows Store not opening
Windows Store not opening

Before you go through the recommended solutions, make sure your Windows PC qualifies these basic requirements:

You have enabled UAC (User Account Control)
You have an active internet connection to connect to store and download apps
Your PC’s minimum screen resolution is 1024 x 768
Your Video card driver is updated
1] Adjust your date and time settings DateTimeSettings

Having an incorrect date/time settings is the most common yet unnoticed thing. To adjust your date/time settings follow these steps:

Press Windows key + W, which opens up charms bar, type in “Date and time”.
Select the “Change date and time”
Adjust the correct date and time by clicking on “Change date and time” time
Also adjust the exact time zone depending on your region
2] Disable Proxy Connection Internet_Options Your proxy settings might be stopping your Windows store from opening. Follow these steps to disable your internet proxy settings:

Press Windows key + W, which opens up charms bar, type in “Internet Options”.
Select the “Internet Options” which opens up “Internet Properties” window.
Under the “Connections” tab click on “LAN Settings”
Uncheck “Use Proxy server” option and click on “OK”
Method2

3] Run the Windows 8 Apps Troubleshooter

When this App troubleshooter is run, it automatically fixes some of the basic issues that might be preventing your Store or apps from running – such as lower screen resolution, incorrect security or account settings, etc.

4] Clear Windows store cache

WSReset

Press Windows key + R to open run box.
Type WSReset.exe and hit enter.
By doing this, all store cache and corrupt settings are reset and your Windows store shall open normally. This post details the Reset Windows Store cache feature.

Comment: External links can break, in which case your answer wouldn't contain even a clue to a solution.  For this reason, we ask that you include the essential information within your answer and use the links for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, your links didn't help me out. The problem still remains.

Comment: Then we have to use the hard way, before that please check that cumulative update is KB3081438 has been installed!

PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {$manifest = (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore).InstallLocation + '\AppxManifest.xml' ; Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $manifest}" 

If it still doesn't work try to use another microsoft account!

Comment: I don't see KB3081438 in my update history. However, it said that my laptop is up to date. I also try the above PowerShell, but it doesn't work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  *If you update your answer to include the relevant information I will reverse my vote.*  It actually is the only way I can reverse it, because after 5 minutes, my vote is locked in.